# Question with .htaccess and wp-login.php prevention

Tags: htaccess

I've noticed an 'error' in an .htaccess rule that I read in a tutorial. What I am trying to do is prevent access to wp-login.php using a very common .htaccess rule which is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.122$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.122$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, the problem with this is that it creates an eternal 'loop' because the 403 page which the user with the invalid IP is sent to is then presented with a page that they cannot access. So, my question is - is it possible to hardcode a URL on the [R=403,L] line of code? I was thinking, perhaps something like:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=/folder/index.php,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution - this needs to be added to the .htaccess

```
 ErrorDocument 403 /path-to-your-site/index.php?error=404
```